# Symfony2: Unique constraint for a string property is not working for values set in prePersist() method in a subscriber class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a form where a user enters his phone number. A common problem is that a phone number can be written in many different ways: "+49 711 XXXXXX", "0049 (0)711 XXXXXX" or "+49 711 - XXXXXX" are all presentations of the same phone number. In order to detect duplicates I use the "phone-number-bundle" (https://github.com/misd-service-development/phone-number-bundle) to get a "normalized" E.164 representation of the phone number that can be used for comparison. If a duplicate is detected, the entered number must not be stored and a notice has to be shown to the user.

If the entered phone number is a valid phone number, I want to check if the E.164-formatted value of the phone number is already stored in the database table.

This is the MySQL table for phone numbers:

```
-+----+---------------------+----------------+
 | id | original            | phonenumber    |
-+----+---------------------+----------------+
 | 1  | 0711-xxxxxxx        | +49711xxxxxxx  |
-+----+---------------------+----------------+
 | 2  | +49 7034 / xxxxx-xx | +497034xxxxxxx |
-+----+---------------------+----------------+
 | 3  | +49 (0)171/xxxxxxx  | +49171xxxxxxx  |
-+----+---------------------+----------------+
 | .. | ...                 | ...            |
-+----+---------------------+----------------+
```

"phonenumber" contains the E.164 formatted value of the value entered in the form. The first originally entered value is stored in the column "original" as additional information.

The form is defined in "src/AppBundle/Form/PhonenumberType.php":

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use libphonenumber\PhoneNumberFormat;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class PhonenumberType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            //->add('phonenumber') // Remove comments to see that the unique constraint works when the phonenumber is submitted via form
            ->add('original')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Phonenumber'
        ));
    }
}
```

Phonenumber Entity "src/AppBundle/Entity/Phonenumber.php":

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use AppBundle\Validator\Constraints as PhonenumberAssert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * Phonenumber
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="phonenumber",
 *     uniqueConstraints={
 *          @ORM\UniqueConstraint(columns={"phonenumber"})
 *      })
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity("phonenumber")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Phonenumber
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="phonenumber", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $phonenumber;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="original", type="string", length=255, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @PhonenumberAssert\IsValidPhoneNumber
     */
    private $original;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Returns phonenumber.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getPhonenumber();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set phonenumber
     *
     * @param string $phonenumber
     *
     * @return Phonenumber
     */
    public function setPhonenumber($phonenumber)
    {
        $this->phonenumber = $phonenumber;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get phonenumber
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPhonenumber()
    {
        return $this->phonenumber;
    }

    /**
     * Set original
     *
     * @param string $original
     *
     * @return Phonenumber
     */
    public function setOriginal($original)
    {
        $this->original = $original;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get original
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOriginal()
    {
        return $this->original;
    }
}
```

Defined services in "app/config/services.yml":

```
services:
    phonenumber_validation:
        class: AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\IsValidPhoneNumberValidator
        arguments: ["@service_container"]
        tags:
            - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: phonenumber_validation }

    my.subscriber:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\PhoneNumberNormalizerSubscriber
        calls:
            - [setContainer, ["@service_container"]]
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
```

The subscriber class "src/AppBundle/EventListener/PhoneNumberNormalizerSubscriber.php":

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use AppBundle\Entity\Phonenumber;
use libphonenumber\NumberParseException;
use libphonenumber\PhoneNumber;
use libphonenumber\PhoneNumberFormat;
use libphonenumber\PhoneNumberUtil;

class PhoneNumberNormalizerSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    /** @var ContainerInterface */
    protected $container;

    /**
     * @param ContainerInterface @container
     */
    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            'prePersist',
            'preUpdate',
        );
    }

    // Executed when data is stored for the first time
    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        // only act on "Phonenumber" entity
        if ($entity instanceof Phonenumber)
        {
            $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();
            $phoneNumberObj = $this->container->get('libphonenumber.phone_number_util')->parse($entity->getOriginal(), 'DE');
            $normalized_phonenumber = $this->container->get('libphonenumber.phone_number_util')->format($phoneNumberObj, PhoneNumberFormat::E164);
            $entity->setPhonenumber($normalized_phonenumber);
        }
    }

    // Executed when data is already stored
    public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        // only act on "Phonenumber" entity
        if ($entity instanceof Phonenumber)
        {
            $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();
            $phoneNumberObj = $this->container->get('libphonenumber.phone_number_util')->parse($entity->getOriginal(), 'DE');
            $normalized_phonenumber = $this->container->get('libphonenumber.phone_number_util')->format($phoneNumberObj, PhoneNumberFormat::E164);
            $entity->setPhonenumber($normalized_phonenumber);
        }
    }

}
```

The constraint class "src/AppBundle/Validator/Constraints/IsValidPhoneNumber.php":

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class IsValidPhoneNumber extends Constraint
{
    public $message_invalid = 'Not a valid phone number: "%string%"';

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return 'phonenumber_validation';
    }
}
```

The validator class "src/AppBundle/Validator/Constraints/IsValidPhoneNumberValidator.php":

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
use libphonenumber\NumberParseException;
use libphonenumber\PhoneNumber;
use libphonenumber\PhoneNumberFormat;
use libphonenumber\PhoneNumberUtil;

class IsValidPhoneNumberValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{

    private $container;

    /**
     * Construct
     */
    public function __construct(Container $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    /**
     * Validate
     *
     * @param mixed $value
     * @param Constraint $constraint
     */
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if ($value != '' )
        {
            $phoneNumberObj = $this->container->get('libphonenumber.phone_number_util')->parse($value, 'DE');

            if (!$this->container->get('libphonenumber.phone_number_util')->isValidNumber($phoneNumberObj))
            {
                $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message_invalid)
                    ->setParameter('%string%', $value)
                    ->addViolation();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The phone number validator works - if a number is invalidated by the "phone-number-bundle", a message "Not a valid phone number: "3333333333333333" is displayed. The E.164 formatted value gets also saved correctly into the database table.

Problem: Although I use "@ORM\UniqueConstraint(columns={"phonenumber"})", "@UniqueEntity("phonenumber")" and "unique=true" for the $phonenumber attribute in the entity class, every entered valid number from the form gets stored in the database, no matter if there is already a duplicate in the table or not. The unique constraint does not work when the phonenumber field is not added in the form type class.

May be interesting: When I remove the comment in the PhonenumberType class so that

```
->add('phonenumber')
```

is included again and an existing number is entered in the associated form field "phonenumber", I get "This value is already used." like expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, it is not.
You have to differentiate:

- Form validation. It occurs when your controller calls `$form->handle($request)` or something similar, triggered on a form event
- Doctrine callbacks, that are called during the EntityManager `flush()`

The solution is then to use that bundle not on `prePersist()`, but rather on a Form event. Data will be normalized before writing it to the entity, then effectively validating what you will save to DB.

Such a code would look like this:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use libphonenumber\PhoneNumberFormat;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

class PhonenumberType extends AbstractType
{
    private $phoneNumberUtil;

    public function __construct(PhoneNumberUtil $phoneNumberUtil)
    {
         $this->phoneNumberUtil = $phoneNumberUtil;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('phonenumber', 'hidden')
            ->add('original')
            ->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) use ($this) {
                  $entity = $event->getData();

                  $phoneNumber = $this->phoneNumberUtil->parse($entity->getOriginal(), PhoneNumberUtil::UNKNOWN_REGION);
                  $normalized_phonenumber = $this->phoneNumberUtil->format($phoneNumberObj, PhoneNumberFormat::E164);

                  $entity->setPhoneNumber($normalized_phonenumber);
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Phonenumber'
        ));
    }
}
```

One more thing, declaring your form type as a service will make the build simplfer, have a look there: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#defining-your-forms-as-services

Edit, here is the YML service definition:

```
app.contact_type:
    class: AppBundle\Form\PhonenumberType
    arguments:
        - @libphonenumber.phone_number_util
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: 'phone_number' }
```

Comment: Thank you! Your proposal using addEventListener() lead me in the right direction. I do not know if my actual solution follows best practices, but it works. More precisely, I adapted this service definition: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204219/symfony2-how-to-get-config-parameters-in-form-classes#34671558). That way I can access the libphonenumber services by `$this->container->get('libphonenumber.phone_number_util')`

Comment: Avoid passing the container directly: it is too much. I will update my answer with the service definition in YML.

Comment: Works perfectly now, thanks a lot! One thing that should be mentioned is that I first had to remove the `use ($this)` statement in the form type definition. Before removal I got an error: "Cannot use $this as lexical variable". I did not further investigate that but it seems that newer PHP versions have a problem with it (I'm using PHP 5.6)

Comment: Exactly, that syntax changed in PHP 5.4 I think. Great our works!